Flutter web sharing state across browser tab
I develop POS system using Flutter Web.
In POS system we need to have second screen to display the ordered product.
My question is:
1.Is there any way to share state in flutter web?
2.If can't ,Is there any solution with my case ?
Thanks.
I do some research , have a few option in my case :
1.Web socket
2.Storage
...
But i don't know it's a good practice or not.
